# php artisan migrate on Azure (in BitBucket pipeline)

Tags: laravel, azure, bitbucket, laravel-artisan, bitbucket-pipelines

I have setup a pipeline in BitBucket to automatically deploy my master branch of my project to an Azure Web App instance.

The app deploys the files and runs `composer update` as expected (although it does warn that it's running as root), but `php artisan migrate --force` returns:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'forge'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO) (SQL: select
>   * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations)

I have already created the `.env` file, and when I run `php artisan migrate` from within a shell it runs successfully and the tables are created.

Being that 'forge' is the default user in `database.php` I figure `.env` isn't being loaded when the command is fired from the deploy script.

Is there something obvious I've missed to cause this issue, or should I somehow set it up to not run as root?
I could replace the database details in `database.php` but I feel that's the wrong thing to do.

**edit**

.env contents (with certain data replaced with ********):

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=********
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=********

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=********
DB_DATABASE=********
DB_USERNAME=********
DB_PASSWORD=********

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

**edit 2**

I realise I'm yet to publish my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file:

```
image: php:7.2-fpm

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -qy git curl libmcrypt-dev mysql-client && apt-get install -qy unzip git
            - yes | pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
            - docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer update
            - php artisan migrate --force
            - php artisan serve --port=80 &
            - sleep 5
            - curl -vk http://localhost:80
          deployment: staging
          services:
            - mysql

definitions:
  services:
    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '******'
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        MYSQL_USER: '******'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '******'
        MYSQL_PORT: '******'
```

I also have a `.env.pipelines` file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=******
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=******
DB_USERNAME=******
DB_PASSWORD=******
```

Comment: What's the content of the `.env` file before you run `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: I've edited my original question to include the `.env` file contents

Comment: Do you have any other `.env[...]` files (besides `.env.example`)?

Comment: I have a `.env-pipelines` file which I've just included in the question, along with my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file

Comment: Can you edit your application files before running `php artisan migrate`? The result of `dd(\App::environment(), env('DB_USERNAME'));` in `AppServiceProvider::boot()` would be interesting.

Comment: In general, StackEchange sites prefer people not mark edits when they are made, as the system has an change tracker making the "edit" markers unnecessary.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir That returns the correct database username

Answer (score 3):

This error basically comes from the after changes in the `.env` file:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'forge'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO) (SQL: select
>   * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations)

Whenever we change the `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` in `.env` file, we need to clear the cache.

After completion of `.env` edit, must be clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

NOTE: If no password is set on the database, clear it `DB_PASSWORD`, **empty space must also be removed**(In the past I've also faceout this problem, It's consider blank space as a password)

Comment: I have run `php artisan config:cache` after changing the `.env` file and still the same error - I've also restarted the Web App instance with the same result.

Comment: Hello @RichardHedges Maybe you have a problem with some other codes, But with this solution your problem can be solved. I am giving you a solution from my previous experience, I had a problem similar to yours.

Comment: I'm not sure what other 'codes' could be causing this problem, as nothing else has been changed. I've tried running this with a fresh Laravel installation using the correct database details, and when I run `php artisan migrate` from the command line it works fine - but when running from BitBucket pipelines it doesn't use the correct variables from `.env`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your deploy script and how you are connecting with your Azure server you would need to put

`php artisan config:clear` // This will reload the .env file to cache

after you have connected to your server but before you run

`php artisan migrate`

Comment: I've added the deploy script to the original question now, and I've run `php artisan config:clear` but still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#configuration-caching

`php artisan config:cache`

The above command will just regenerate the cache for you. (if added as a part of deployment script)

Else you can use `php artisan config:clear` just to clear the existing config and fetch values from .env/config files (add as a part of your deployment script)

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache but still the same problem.

Comment: Ok, Do like this, on your server create a .env file in a separate directory let's say /home/<user>/config/.env and in your deployment script  just add a command at last, which just symlink the .env file to that location, similar like `ln -s <file_loc> .env`.

As generally we don't commit `.env` , seems like your .env is not even present in your build folder.

Comment: I have already created a `.env` file in the same directory as `artisan` though - the file definitely exists. I'll give your suggestion a run through later.

Comment: Refer https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/laravel-with-bitbucket-pipelines-913473967.html